# sum and count confusion

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I can't understand the difference between count and sum

I'm trying to get the number of rows for a specific condition of my report and always I get 0 using count or sum

```
columnA columnB
0       my string  
0       none
0       my string  
0       none
1       none
```

=`IIF((Fields!columnA.Value = "0" and Fields!columnB.Value = "none"), SUM(Fields!columnA .Value),0)`

I want to get 2 as a result
I can't see my error

Comment: The IIF will be false for the columnA=1. This means you have 3 false and 2 true conditions. Your required output implies the false condition which gives "3". Not "2". And learn to vote/accept answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUM() will return the total of the values in that field, while count will return the number of **non null** values.

So in the example you provided, `=SUM(Fields!columnA.value)` should return 0 and `=COUNT(Fields!columnA.value)` should return 5. [ But your IIF statement makes it sound like this is in a location where the scope is a single row, so then the count and Sum will only be applied to that row. If you want to scope the expression for the entire group, add a scope parameter to your aggregate function, such as `COUNT(Fields!columnA.value, "MyDataSetName")` ]

Since you aren't seeing this result, there are a few things you can check:

- Are you really getting back 0 for your query, or is it possible that
  you are getting a null value back?
- Are you using this expression
  somewhere where the scope matches what you expect? That is, if you
  want it to count all rows in your data set are you using it in a top
  level textbox or group total?

Also, simplify to debug: place the individual components of your IIF statement in different cells, so that you can verify that the values match what you think should be happening.

Comment: I'm very sure that I'm not getting null data from my query, I change it to return a data when the result were NULL. I'm not using a group, I want to use the result in a top level textgroup. I'm using a countrows() in the top level as well and it is work.

Comment: I'm using this expression in my textbox =IIF(Fields!CompletedBy.Value = "PDA",Count(Fields!CompletedBy.Value),0) and I got as a result the total of ALL rows, the same value that I got from countrows(). and I want to get only the number of rows that contain "PDA" in the field CompletedBy

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `COUNT`. The `SUM` of 0 + 0 for column A will return you 0. `COUNT` will return you the number of matching records. If `COUNT` doesn't work then there is something wrong with your grouping (aggregate) or filtering condition matching the data.

Comment: I'm using count IIF((Fields!OrderCompletedOnPDA.Value = "0" and Fields!CompletedBy.Value = "NONE"), COUNT(Fields!OrderCompletedOnPDA.Value), 0) and I'm sure that I'm getting this dataset from my sp . I can't undestand how in this case is doesn't work

Comment: now I change my sp to use to not use a complicate expressino in iff. Now I'm using  =IIF(Fields!CompletedBy.Value = "PDA",Count(Fields!CompletedBy.Value),0)  and this give me the total of rows that I got from countRows.. I can't undestand why the other doesn't work for me!!!

Comment: It must be NULL data or scope causing the issue. Take a look at the SSRS specification for COUNT http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157163(SQL.100).aspx